# move my progressbar with an image android

Tags: android, xml, image, progress-bar

i have this code

is a progress bar that fill with a red color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <gradient
            android:startColor="#c3c3c3"
                android:centerColor="#c3c3c3"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#7f7f7f"
                android:angle="270"/>
            <padding android:left="1dp"
            android:top="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:bottom="1dp"/> 
        <corners android:radius="10dp"/> 
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#234"
                android:centerColor="#234"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#a24"
                android:angle="270"/>
            <padding android:left="1dp"
                android:top="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:bottom="1dp"/> 
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/> 
            </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
       <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#a42c48"
                android:centerColor="#a42c48"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#eb3e67"
                android:angle="270"/>
            <padding android:left="1dp"
                android:top="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:bottom="1dp"/> 
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/> 
        </shape>
    </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and look like this

[image]

now i want to add an image to move at the same time the progress bar fills up like the image below

[image]

please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe you could style a seekbar (instead of a progressbar) using your layerlist and add your image as the thumb scrubber?

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:thumb="@drawable/your_android_image"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/your_layerlist_drawable"/>
```

Comment: thanks Damian for the answer. Do you have an example how to do that please

Comment: no probs. I did a quick test and it looks good. You'll probably want to call seekBar.setEnabled(false); in your activity so that the user can't interact with the seekbar.

Comment: That's exactly what i want to do in my app, i appreciate your help Damian

Answer (score 8):

I think this moving image can be done using seekbar, this image is called thum drawable

[image]

You can try this [tutorial](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/) it will help you a lot!!

set the seekbar attribute `android:thumb="@drawable/seek_thumb"` to point to the drawable that you desire

Comment: Very good example K_Anas, now i have a better look about seekbar