# Custom ProgressBar With Thumb Android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

What is the best way to achieve the `progressbar` with the `thumb` found on my [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o2rqmons6ri35eu/-qG5tMDDTq?lst) . The thumb is a picture. I tried it using two `progressbars`, one `progressbar` without thumb and the second i set the progress bar transparent and add the thumb picture below. It works but the `progressbar` and the `thumb` `onProgress` does not run parallel. I heard something about nine patch image. However i want to know if there is a property to show the thumb below progressbar like the image on my drive.

Comment: Hello. See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921703/move-my-progressbar-with-an-image-android

Comment: nice i tried it it works like charm :) brillant example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For create custom ProgressBar You need to create xml for that.

Go through [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921703/move-my-progressbar-with-an-image-android). I think it will help you.

Thanks. Happy Codding.